# javascript check if checkbox is not checked not hiding div onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies, checkbox

I am checking on a page if a checkbox is checked, and if it is not, I want to hide a div. I am not sure if it is due to my div not having an inline element, but I cannot use that method anyway. I am also using cookies to remember what selection is chosen for each user. The cookies section works fine, it's just the hiding of the div that is not working. Here is the code:

```
  function setCookie(c_name,value,expiredays) {
    var exdate=new Date()
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate()+expiredays)
    document.cookie=c_name+ "=" +escape(value)+((expiredays==null) ? "" : ";expires="+exdate)
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    if (document.cookie.length>0) {
        c_start=document.cookie.indexOf(c_name + "=")
        if (c_start!=-1) { 
            c_start=c_start + c_name.length+1 
            c_end=document.cookie.indexOf(";",c_start)
            if (c_end==-1) c_end=document.cookie.length
                return unescape(document.cookie.substring(c_start,c_end))
        } 
    }
    return null
}

function checkCookie(){
document.getElementById('john').checked = getCookie('calOption1')==1? true : false;
document.getElementById('steve').checked = getCookie('calOption2')==1? true : false;
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('#john').is(':checked')) {
       $('.ms-acal-color2').css('display', 'block');
    }else{
    $('.ms-acal-color2').css('display', 'none');
    }
});

$('#john').change(function() {
if (this.checked) { //if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('.ms-acal-color2').css('display', 'block');
} else {
      $('.ms-acal-color2').css('display', 'none');
};
}); 

}

function set_check(){
setCookie('calOption1', document.getElementById('john').checked? 1 : 0, 100);
setCookie('calOption2', document.getElementById('steve').checked? 1 : 0, 100);
}
```

EDIT: here is the html code

```
<div style="float: left;">
  <div id="myForm">
    <input type="checkbox" onchange="set_check();" id="john"/>
    <label>Show John</label>
      <input type="checkbox" onchange="set_check();" id="steve"/>
      <label>Show Steve</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that in some browsers (e.g. IE up to and including 8 at least), a checkbox will not dispatch a change event until it loses focus. Better to use a click event instead.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I replaced the change to click, and it is still very buggy, this is in IE10. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is a mess :) you shoudn't be joining javascript sintax with jquery, use just one of them...

You are also confusing some things, you are adding document ready listener inside a function, and other event listeners too ...

I cleaned up your code, look at the result here: http://jsfiddle.net/Hezrm/
To see it working with the cookies: http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/Hezrm/show

Here are the changes in **Javascript**:

```
// In the Document Ready listener you are going to check cookies and
// hide "everyone" that is not checked
$(document).ready(function() {
    checkCookie();
    $(".person:not(:checked)").next().hide();
});

// This is a change eventlistener that will hide or show people at runtime
$('#john, #steve').change(function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) $(this).next().show();
    else $(this).next().hide();
    set_check(); // And save changes to cookies
}); 

function checkCookie(){
    $('#john').attr("checked", getCookie('calOption1') == 1 ? true : false);
    $('#steve').attr("checked", getCookie('calOption2') == 1 ? true : false);
}

function set_check(){
    setCookie('calOption1', $('#john').is(':checked')? 1 : 0, 100);
    setCookie('calOption2', $('#steve').is(':checked')? 1 : 0, 100);
}
```

I also added a class `.person` to make it easier to hide or show the checkboxes:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="john" class="person"/>
```

Comment: By the way, this: `.css('display', 'block')` is equal to this: `.show()`, and `.css('display', 'none')` = `.hide()`

Comment: Thankyou Toni, much appreciated. I know its a mess, just hacked together from various sites really, surprised it works now that you mention it. Just one thing for me to change, it's not the checkboxes I want to hide, its 2 divs, (say div1 & div2). So if checkbox #steve is not ticked, I want to hide div2 on page load.

Comment: Just tried editing the fiddle, I can't see which piece of code is hiding the labels (eg-Show John)? Just need to change this to my div, not the label.

Comment: Ah ok, I going to update the fiddle ... I'm using .next().hide() so it will hide the next object to the checkbox, the label ...

Comment: @binga30 I replaced the `.next().hide()` or `.next().show()` for `if($("#john").is(':checked')) $("#john-div").show(); else $("#john-div").hide();` its easier to understand

Comment: Thank you Toni, I am going to mark this as the answer, but just one more thing. Under the manageDivs function, this is only occuring onload, not on every change/click for me.

Comment: It works on fiddle right? I'm doing the `on change` here: `$('#john, #steve').change(function() { manageDivs(); }); `

Comment: `manageDivs()` needs to occur at document ready, and at every checkbox change ...

Comment: Yeh the fiddle is perfect, just isn't quite performing on my page. I am using Sharepoint 2010 however.